# Desktop screen goes black because of radiowaves from phone?

Tags: interference

I hope this is the right community for this phenomenon.

For some weeks my desktop screen went black for some seconds - no warning prompt no nothing - and then came back to life.

I usually change my phone directly below the monitor.

Today, the monitor was stable until I exited the airplane-mode of my smartphone. Then the weird behavior started again. When I put the phone in airplane mode the screen went black one last time and since then is stable again.

I noted that my built in PC speaker next to the monitor sometimes makes some noise due to the phone.

Also: Interestingly the disturbance of my desktop monitor started about the time I switched carriers.

My questions are:

- Does this make sense?
- How much can my phone influence the circuits of the desktop screen?
- Would it be possible that changing carriers has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How much can my phone influence the circuits of the desktop screen?

The phone contains an RF transmitter for communicating with the cellular network. If the closest "basestation" of cellular network is far away or there is a lot of interference, then your phone will transmit at higher power  in order to compensate for that.

The phone maintains a wireless connection to the cellular network so periodically it has to let the network know it is still ready to receive a call. For that it needs to transmit signals to the cellular network. Those transmitted signals can also be picked up by other equipment. The most common phenomenon I have experienced is when radios and (PC) speakers start to make click-bzz sounds when the phone is transmitting.

Depending on the design of your monitor, that monitor could be disturbed such that it thinks there's no signal present or that it needs to switch inputs. That can happen if the electronics in the monitor aren't shielded well enough.

Generally monitors aren't designed to not be disturbed by a phone transmitting at maximum power closeby. I see it as "bad luck" that your monitor is sensitive in this respect. A different monitor could respond differently or not at all.

> Would it be possible that changing carriers has something to do with it?

Yes, the carrier could use a different frequency band which could work better or worse in your situation. It can also be that a different carrier has a basestation that is closer to your location and then your phone can transmit at a lower power but still keep the connection.

Possible solutions are:

- placing the phone further away from other equipment
- changing the type of network connection, maybe you're using 2G (GSM) but 3G or 4G (LTE) could also be available. Most phones have a setting for this so try that. It depends on the phone and the cellular network what is supported and what is not.
- not preffered but I mention it anyway: shield the sensitive equipment by using tinfoil of copper foil or any other electrically conductive material.

Comment: Thanks for the many options! This was really bugging me, as the Monitor turned off every minute or so. Yes, the base station seems to be far away since I have little connection bars. Now that I know, I will try using the a different network, though 3G is not available any more. Another workaround I will use for now is to redirect phone calls from my mobile to my landline if the phone is not connected and then switch the phone to airplane mode. I may just switch back to the former carrier and let you know if this solved the problem.

Comment: Switching the carrier removed the problem.